# Why is my port source changing with every UDP message I send?

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I'm tracking the UDP messages I'm sending from my android phone on Wireshark, but the source port number changes every time I send a message.

So I have two questions:

1. Is this bad if I want to receive messages back? Or would it be find, just each received message comes through a different port?
2. If the answer to 1) is yes it is bad, then what should I do to change that?
   Here's my code:

edit: Full code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 1111;
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "255.255.255.255";

    private LinearLayout msgList;
    private EditText edMessage;
    private int clientTextColor;

    private ClientThread clientThread;
    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        msgList = findViewById(R.id.msgList);
        edMessage = findViewById(R.id.edMessage);
        clientTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    
    // Just for displaying messages on device 
    public TextView textView(String message, int color) {...}

    public void showMessage(final String message, final int color) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                msgList.addView(textView(message, color));
            }
        });
    }

    // Implementation

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.clear) {
            msgList.removeAllViews();
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.send_data) {
            // Starting thread
            clientThread = new ClientThread();
            thread = new Thread(clientThread);
            thread.start();

            String clientMessage = edMessage.getText().toString().trim(); // Client's Message
            showMessage(clientMessage, Color.BLUE); // Just display
            if (null != clientThread) {
                clientThread.sendMessage(clientMessage + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
                        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                        ds.receive(dp);
                        String serverMsg = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());

                        showMessage("Server: " + serverMsg, clientTextColor);
                        ds.close();
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        void sendMessage(final String message) { // Called by "Send Data" button
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        byte[] msg = message.getBytes();
                        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg, msg.length, ip, SERVERPORT);
                        socket.setBroadcast(true);
                        socket.send(packet);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    String getTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        return sdf.format(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != clientThread) {
            clientThread.sendMessage("Disconnect");
            clientThread = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UDP is unsuitable for a sustained communication.  Use TCP if you need to track "who" the sender is.

Comment: But you can still receive messages through UDP, correct? Are you saying that the port source just doesn't matter?

Comment: @qol: Can you receive a letter which is addressed to you but where the senders address was only temporary and does not exist anymore? Yes, you can receive the letter.  You could even reply to it, but the original sender would not receive your reply. That's what you essentially do in your code.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry I meant could the sender not receive a message back. And in your analogy wouldn't the address be like the IP address which the initial receiver has?

Comment: @qol: In your code there is no attempt to receive by the client (sender) and no attempt to send by the server, but it depends on the actual code. If the sender socket still exists than it can be used for receiving data from the server. Similar on the server side the server has to reply to the address where the latest message came from.

Comment: Hmm ok, there actually isn't a server that I'm messaging, it's just another device on the same ethernet network.. Also, is the code in the "run" function not an attempt to receive by the client? What would I have to change to do what you mentioned? Do I need to move the code in the sendMessage() into the run() to use the same socket or something? Vice versa? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Where do you define the actual value of SERVERPORT?

Comment: @qol: I'm actually confused by your code. Why does something you call __client__ wants to receive data on what you call __server__ port? And you specifically have a server_ip to connect to and call the one connecting the client, so my understanding is that you clearly distinguish between a client and a server role. The common setup is though that the client is  creating 1 socket and use this for sending and receiving. You instead create one socket for receiving (on server port) and then a new socket for each sent message.

Comment: @einUsername at the start, I posted my full code in my edit

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hmmm, I took the code I used for TCP and just altered it to use UDP because I couldn't find any good resources for UDP.. and so maybe that's why the code looks weird... I guess "client" just means "device 1" and "server" just means "device 2 (receiver)". Right now also, the server ip is just 255.255.255.255 to broadcast to every device on the network. I want to receive the message that the devices are programmed to send back to any device (like my android phone) that sends it a message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That does seem like the smarter idea though, creating just one socket, how should I implement that? Do I just move the code snippet from the sendMessage function and put it into run(). The thing I'm most confused about with network programming is how is the code supposed to continuously run and listen for messages while at the same time being able to run a function that sends a message?

Comment: You mean get rid of clientThread completely? Are you saying I don't need to use run()/runnable? How do I implement an infinite loop listening for messages then? @einUsername I posted the code in a separate answer below, can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: `255.255.255.255` hasn't worked for about 30 years. I suggest you investigate UDP multicast.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are creating a new socket with each iteration, which will open a new port. That's how multiple clients can communicate with a server in parallel.

1. Most servers will capture your IP address and port, so it will respond correctly to your socket, but you have to make sure your socket object is persistent long enough to observe.
2. Bad depends on the goal. Create a socket open as long as you need to communicate to the server, in that process, with that socket. You don't need to open another socket because you are initiating a new message.